# magic bytes (or removing latest newlines from being piped)

Tags: bash, pipe, newline

as i was messing with multipart messages i encountered some strange behavior evaluating the content length of multipart message bodies.

long story short. it can be broke down to newlines being piped.

```
$ a="x"; b="y"
$ echo -e "${a}" | wc -c
2 # strange, shouldn't it be just a single byte?
$ echo -e "${b}" | wc -c
2 # at this point one could guess the sum is **4**, but its not
$ echo -e "${a}${b}" | wc -c
3
$ echo -e "${a}${b}" | hexdump -C 
00000000  78 79 0a  |xy.|
00000003
```

**is there a possibility to avoid the magic/invisible byte being piped
or - if not possible - at least removed?**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic character you're referring to, is a newline character `\n`. A newline simply tells the terminal emulator you're running to — you guessed it — print a newline!

`echo` by default appends a newline to the end of your string, so your string doesn't end up on the same line as your prompt.

`echo` can be passed `-n`, which prevents it from appending a newline to the end of your string. You could also use the `printf` command which does not append a newline by default.

I suggest `printf` over `echo`, as there are many portability problems with `echo` now-a-days.

So, in the end, a sample command could look like:

`printf "${a}" | wc -c`

Or with `echo`:

`echo -en "${a}" | wc -c`

Comment: thanks. it seems to work. i was afraid of using this due it possibly would have removed all newlines if `${a}` contained multiple newlines but it seems that `-n` just handles the last newline.

Comment: Indeed, '-n' will  only prevent `echo` from *appending* a newline. It does nothing to the string to be echo'd.

Comment: There are additional reasons to prefer `printf "%s" "${a}"` over `echo -n "${a}"`, for example when `a="-n"` echo will print nothing!

Comment: @joeytwiddle, I agree with you, and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) are more reasons as well.